# Sendmail process crashes as soon as STARTTLS is received

Tags: freebsd, sendmail, openssl, starttls

I just upgraded my server from FreeBSD 10.3 to 11.1.  It's now running Sendmail 8.15.2 and OpenSSL 1.0.2k-freebsd  26 Jan 2017.

Since the upgrade, sending mail *to* my server is failing.  I cranked up the log level to show all incoming and outgoing SMTP commands using `/usr/sbin/sendmail -d95.99 -bD -X /tmp/test.log`.  A typical incoming connection looks like this:

```
34431 >>> 220 localhost.FKEinternet.net ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2; Thu, 8 Mar 2018 11:35:32 -0500 (EST)
34431 <<< EHLO [192.168.14.73]
34431 >>> 250-localhost.FKEinternet.net Hello rrcs-184-74-100-26.nys.biz.rr.com [184.74.100.26], pleased to meet you
34431 >>> 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
34431 >>> 250-PIPELINING
34431 >>> 250-8BITMIME
34431 >>> 250-SIZE
34431 >>> 250-DSN
34431 >>> 250-ETRN
34431 >>> 250-STARTTLS
34431 >>> 250-DELIVERBY
34431 >>> 250 HELP
34431 <<< STARTTLS
```

and in `/var/log/messages` I find

```
Mar  8 11:35:32 Dreamer kernel: pid 34431 (sendmail), uid 0: exited on signal 11
```

Is there a crash log somewhere I can look at to figure out what's going on? What else can I do to debug this problem?

---

**EDIT**

Other than instances of `sh.core`, `pkg.core` and `pkg-static.core` created during the server upgrade two days ago, `find / -name "*.core" -ls` did not return any core files less than a year old.  Where there's a sendmail instance crashing with *every* piece of mail being attempted for delivery, I would have expected to find one not more than a few minutes old.  What would be likely to prevent the `.core` files from being created?

Comment: Signal 11 should produce a core dump unless system settings prevent that. But more generally.... sendmail in 2018?

Comment: Yes, I'm still using the same MTA I was 20 years ago - because I haven't seen a compelling reason to make the heavy investment required to change to a different one.

Comment: ulimit is the most common way of preventing coredumps, but I don't have much experience with freebsd. The core dumps should be created in the working directory of the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in DutchDaemon's Dec 12, 2017 reply in the [[sendmail] Lots of "did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN" logs](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/sendmail-lots-of-did-not-issue-mail-expn-vrfy-etrn-logs.45058/#post-368876) thread on the FreeBSD forums:

*A standard install will put something like this in your .mc file:*

```
dnl Enable STARTTLS for receiving email.
define(`CERT_DIR', `/etc/mail/certs')dnl
define(`confSERVER_CERT', `CERT_DIR/host.cert')dnl
define(`confSERVER_KEY', `CERT_DIR/host.key')dnl
define(`confCLIENT_CERT', `CERT_DIR/host.cert')dnl
define(`confCLIENT_KEY', `CERT_DIR/host.key')dnl
define(`confCACERT', `CERT_DIR/cacert.pem')dnl
define(`confCACERT_PATH', `CERT_DIR')dnl
define(`confDH_PARAMETERS', `CERT_DIR/dh.param')dnl
```

I compared that code block with what was in my server's `.mc` file, and found it was missing the **`define('confDH_PARAMETERS','CERT_DIR/dh.param')dnl`** line. I added that, restarted `sendmail`, and it's working now.

I would still like to know why there were never any `.core` files generated, and as SirDice observed on the FreeBSD forums,

> Odd that it actually crashed though, I would have expected it to
>   produce a failure message and refuse to run, not start and segfault
>   when you try to use it.